# Field with 2 columns

Tags: blackberry, field

I need to make a field with 2 columns in it. Instead of overriding the layout() and draw() methods, I'm looking for something easier, something like using HorizontalFieldManager. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GridFieldManager for that. See the Java Development Guide "[Create a grid layout](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_grid_layout_877557_11.jsp)"

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Blackberry Advanced UI Toolkit](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800608/How_to_-_Implement_advanced_buttons,_fields,_and_managers.html?nodeid=2406256&vernum=0) containers

```
com.blackberry.toolkit.ui.container.TwoColumnField
com.blackberry.toolkit.ui.container.TwoColumnFieldManager
```